# scp files through gateway to remote machine

Tags: copy-paste, scp, ubuntu-11.10, gateway

I can't figure out how to scp a file to another machine if there is a gateway connecting my client machine to the remote server. From my client machine I can connect to both the gateway and subsequently to the remote server using SSH without any problems. 
When I try to scp my directory *dir* to the remote server I have no clue how to move past the gateway, because my ssh connection is actually an two-step approach. Scp'ing *dir* to the gateway first fails, with the remark "Permission denied".

Something like

```
~$:   scp -r /var/www/dir      usrname@remotesrv.com:/var/www/dircp
```

doesn't work and the only approach I found so far involves public/private keys. Is it only possible to copy files through a gateway with keys? And if that's so, can somebody tell me how to overcome the problem with copy&pasting into the terminal which sometimes just won't work (using Ubuntu 11.10). Already installed autokey hoping to circumvent buggy Ubuntu shortcuts by changing them to another hotkey, but the program is crashing all the time.

I would appreciate your help in one way or another!

Comment: If you get a permission denied, maybe the problem is that the `usrname` name you're connecting with is not allowed to write to `/var/www/dircp`. You need to check out on `remotesrv` if you can write to that location.

Comment: I don't think this problem should reproduce normally. I am assuming that **same** command (including same login name) works, when you use key pair, instead of password based authentication.

Comment: @Unknown: writing to the directory of the `remotesrv` does work, as I can login to it using ssh and save a file I wrote with nano to the same directory.